# What causes free throw percentage degredation?

Tags: basketball, nba

I'm curious about Russell Westbrook who was an 84.5% free throw shooter with high volume in 2016 only to be sub 70% since with no prior history of such performance. Is there anything that can be pointed to when free throw percentage degrades in this manner? His volume has decreased but I wouldn't think a smaller sample size would lead to such an extreme skew.

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking.  Are you asking "Why did Russell Westbrook suddenly start having a lower FT%"?  Or are you asking "is this a normal thing for players"?

Comment: The former as the premise doesn't hold water for other players. The only thing I've found is a 2017 rule change that had free throw shooters not go beyond the three-point line in between free throws. Westbrook was known for going past that three-point line prior to that rule change.

Comment: I can’t imagine the question is answerable unfortunately unless Russell has said something about it.  It could be a personal issue (maybe he had a muscle issue that changed his muscle memory, which is largely what FT shooting is, for example).  Or maybe he stopped caring … many possibilities and no good way to tell.